# How can I organize and load packages based configurable properties?

Tags: refactoring, smalltalk, configuration-management, code-cleanup

The system I'm working on can be configurated with different boolean properties. The theorical maximum of different configurations is `2^n` where `n` is the number of such properties.

There is a configuration tool separated from the production code, which uses boolean expressions to select which code packages are loaded.
This tool contains a class that defines methods like `isWithX` or more complex ones like `isWithXwithoutYwithZ`.
A package is basically a list of class extensions that define or redefine some method definitions.
Today the packages are named like `myPackageWithAWithoutBwithCwithDwithoutE`.

Since there is an evolving number of boolean configuration properties, the number of different packages and the size of their names is getting ridiculous and we can't see their names without scrolling all the time.
There is also a lot of code duplication.

EDIT: since production code has no access to the configurated properties the question is now limited to those issues:

- list of package names for each package and each functionality
- how many methods and how to name them

Right now the list of package names is basically all different combinations of names like this one: `myPackageWithAWithoutBwithCwithDwithoutE` except those where there is no behaviour specific to that configuration that we need to implement.

Right now for each package and each functionality: 1 method per package with the name of the functionality.

Comment: Are you allowed to change the package names? That is, are you allowed to have just n packages that all define an inclusion ('myPackageWithX') and then mix those packages to match your configuration?

Comment: from myPackageWithXwithoutY and myPackageWithXwithY I can make a 'parent' package called myPackageWithX and remove some of the duplication but I can't remove all of the subpackages content unless I use if statements or something in the parent one.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot tell you how to solve your specific problem, so I will share with you some hints that might help you get started in finding the design that will actually work for you.

Consider a hierarchy of configuration objects:

```
ConfigurationSettings
  ApplicationSettings
  UserSettings
  DisplaySettings
  ...
```

The abstract class `ConfigurationSettings` provides basic services to read/write settings that belong to any specific *section*. The hierarchy allows for simpler naming conventions because selectors can be reimplemented in different subclasses.

The `ApplicationSettings` subclass plays a different role: it registers all the sections in its `registry` instance variable, a `Dictionary` where the keys are section names and the values the corresponding subclass instances:

```
ApplicationSettings current register: anEmailSettings under: `Email`
```

The abstract class provides the basic services for reading and writing settings:

```
settingsFor: section 
settingAt: key for: section
settingAt: key for: section put: value
```

Subclasses use these services to access individual settings and implement the logic required by the client to test whether the current configuration `is`, `has`, `supports`, etc., a particular feature or combination. These more specific methods are implemented in terms of the more basic `settingAt:for:`.

When a new package registers its own subclass its testing methods become available as follows:

```
self <section>Settings isThisButNotThat
```

where, for instance,

```
emailSettings
  ^(ApplicationSettings current for: 'Email') isThisButNotThat
```

and similarly for any other section. As I mentioned above, the division in subclasses will allow you to have simpler selectors that implicitly refer to the section (`#isThisButNotThat` instead of `#isEmailThisButNotThat`).

One other feature that is important to support Apply/Cancel dialogs for the user to modify settings is provided by two methods:

```
 ConfigurationSettings >> #readFrom:
```

and

```
 ConfigurationSettings >> #writeOn:
```

So, when you open the GUI that displays settings you don't open it on the current instance but on a copy of them

```
settings := ApplicationSettings new readFrom: ApplicationSettings current.
```

Then you present in the GUI this copy to the user. If the user cancels the dialog, you simply forget the copy. Otherwise you apply the changes this way:

```
settings writeOn: ApplicationSettings current
```

The implementation of these two services follows a simple pattern:

```
ApplicationSettings >> readFrom: anApplicationSettings
  registry keysAndValuesDo: [:area :settings | | section |
    section := anApplicationSettings for: area.
    settings readFrom: section]
```

and

```
ApplicationSettings >> writeOn: anApplicationSettings
  registry keysAndValuesDo: [:area :settings | | settings |
    section := anApplicationSettings for: area.
    settings writeOn: section]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand all of the aspects of your problem but maybe you could use a dynamic approach. For example, you could override `#doesNotUnderstand:` to parse the selector sent to the configuration and extract the package names:

```
doesNotUnderstand: aMessage
| stream included excluded  |
"parse selectors like #isWithXwithoutYwithoutZ"
stream := (#isWithXwithoutYwithoutZ allButFirst: 6) asLowercase readStream.
included := Set new.
excluded := Set new.
[ stream atEnd ] whileFalse: [
    (stream peek: 3) = 'out'
        ifTrue: [
            stream next: 3.
            excluded add: (stream upToAll: 'with') ]
        ifFalse: [ included add: (stream upToAll: 'with') ] ].
```

Then, all you need is a bit more code to generate the list of packages from that (I hope).

Comment: Such package names should not exist in the first place I'm searching for a different design of the framework. If I didn't care about performances and team work I could hack something that kind of works using doesNotUnderstand, regular expressions, dynamically compiled methods etc. but I'm not even allowed to use if statements

Comment: I see. Could you add more details to your question? For example: what are legal modifications and where can they be made? What are your goals (e.g. getting rid of those package names)?

Comment: I simplified the question a lot now that I understand why I can't use if statements